# Gdb get frame's function name

Tags: debugging, gdb

I'm looking for a way to get the current function's name from the frame information in GDB. Is that possible? If yes, how can I find the other variables set for a specific frame?

Basically I'm after the same name that's displayed at the beginning of each line when running the `bt` command.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get'? Obtain in a script? Via an API? Tied to the leg of a carrier pigeon?

Comment: Access it for comparison in a `define` block. Get something that I can compare to either an address or a name string in the gdb script.

Comment: recent gdb has Python support. I don't know the exact api to get the frame name but you could start with the python support...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ordinary gdb CLI this can only be done with great difficulty.  You have to use logging to write the output of "frame" to a file; then do processing on the file to extract the name and turn it into a gdb script; then "source" the resulting script.

If you have a Python-enabled gdb, then it is easy.  Use gdb.selected_frame() to get the selected frame.  Then the name is in the frame's function symbol:

```
name = gdb.selected_frame().name()
```

If need be you can expose this to the CLI in various ways; but the simplest is probably to wrap it in a convenience function.  See the docs for information on that.